# How can I delete stored RADIUS wifi credentials when they are added from the Win10 logon screen?

Tags: windows, wifi, windows-10, credentials

I was onboarding a new Surface for a VIP and to get it on the intranet to join it to the domain I entered my own RADIUS credentials at the Windows 10 logon screen. Got the device prepped and onboarded and now I've discovered that Windows remembers these credentials even if I delete the WiFi profile.

Things I have tried

- Delete stored WiFi profile using the Win10 Settings UI when signed in as myself
- Delete stored WiFi profile using a CMD window running as SYSTEM (using psexec)
- Check stored credentials using `rundll32 keymgr.dll,KRShowKeyMgr` from a SYSTEM CMD prompt
- Delete stored WiFI profile & check stored credentils using `rundll32 keymgr.dll,KRShowKeyMgr` from a CMD prompt running as PUBLIC (psexec -> SYSTEM cmd prompt, `runas /user:Public`)

Every one of these steps along the way, I log out and try reconnecting to RADIUS and it just connects without prompting me for credentials, which means it has stored my user credentials somewhere. This also means that when I deliver the laptop to the end user, he won't be able to enter *his* credentials to connect to RADIUS WiFi from the logon screen until I change my AD password. I cannot "Forget" a WiFi network from the logon screen.

This is in a production AD domain environment. We don't push out RADIUS via GPO, but if that's a solution we can set it up easily enough.

Comment: Try netsh wlan show profiles.

Comment: @Vadim - I did. That's what I was referring to by using a CMD window to delete the stored wifi profile.

Comment: @Vadim - To be more specific, when I use netsh, I can see the profile, and delete the profile, but when I go to view networks and connect to the RADIUS wifi it never prompts me for credentials. The RADIUS credentials are stored somewhere other than the wlan profile when entered from the logon screen. Either that or the wlan profile that is created when you connect to RADIUS from the logon screen is stored somewhere other than the user, SYSTEM, or PUBLIC user accounts.